# Why does find -regex command, differ from find | grep?

Tags: linux, command-line

The find command below outputs nothing, and does not find any "include" files or directories.

```
find  -regex "*include*" 2>/dev/null
```

However piping the find command into grep -E seems to find most include files.

```
find ./ 2>/dev/null | grep -E "*include*"
```

I've left out the output since the first is blank and the second matches quite a few files.

I'm starting to need to dig through linux system files to find the answers I need (especially to find macro values). In order to do that I have been using find | grep -E to find the files that that should have the macro I am looking for.

Below is the line I tried today with find (my root directory is /), and nothing is output. I don't want to run the command as root so I pipe the errors out to /dev/null. I checked the errors for regex syntax errors but nothing. Its still looping through all directories since I still get a "find: /var/lib: Permission Denied" Error

```
find  -regex "*include*" 2>/dev/null
```

However this seems to work and give me everything I want.

```
find ./ 2>/dev/null | grep -E "*include*"
```

So my main question is why does find -regex not output the same as find | grep -E ?

Comment: `"*include*"` is not a valid regexp, `".*include.*"` is.

Comment: `find` with a regex tries to match the whole path; it looks like you want files and directories that contain `include` in their name. You can use `-name` for that: `find . -name '*include*'`; notice that `-name` takes a *shell pattern*, not a regular expression as its argument. `*` in a pattern is the same as `.*` in a regular expression.

Comment: thank you all for your input, I've learned alot from your advice!

Comment: Please place answers in Answer blocks. Later, you can accept your own Answer. Also see [How does accepting an answer work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/173448)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regular expressions are not a language, but a general mathematical construct with many different notations and dialects thereof.

For simple patterns you can often get away with ignoring this fact since most dialects use very similar notation, but since you are specifying an ill defined pattern with a leading asterisk, you get into engine specific behavior.

- `grep -E` uses the GNU implementation of POSIX ERE, and interprets your pattern as `()*includ(e)*` and therefore matches `includ` followed by zero or more `e`s. (POSIX says that the behavior of a leading asterisk [is undefined](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/basedefs/V1_chap09.html)).
- `find` uses Emacs Regex, and interprets it as `\*includ(e)*` and therefore requires a literal asterisk in the filename.

If you want the same result from both, you can use `find -regextype posix-egrep`, or you can specify a regex that is equivalent in both such as `.*include.*` to match `include` as a substring.

Comment: Thank you! I am a vim user, so this is good to know. I'm not exactly sure which version of regex vim uses, but I've found it to be very similar to grep.
Marking as solved with your answer!

Comment: Vim has its own pretty unique dialect with a pile of extensions, but for simple patterns with just `*()|[]a-z` it'll indeed behave similarly to `grep` without `-E`

Answer (score 0):

As I understand your question you want to find files in Linux directories

You should use this library

```
yum install locate
```

If you use ubuntu

```
sudo apt-get install locate
```

Prepare library

```
sudo updatedb
```

Then start search

```
locate include
```

Comment: Thank you for the useful linux binary, I will look into using that one as well in the future!